# Launching html file in firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to launch a HTML file in firefox automatically

Our company has IE set as the default and this file is meant to launch in firefox to work properly

This is the code I have to check that, but for some reason it doesn't want to work properly

The filepath is correct which was the first thing I thought of

Can anyone assist?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="opener_files/opener.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function codeAddress(){
                if (browserName = "Internet Explorer");
                var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                shell.run('"Firefox" "file:///Mel19a001ppn/transfer/L&D_LT&S/SimonW/Sean/DEBT T1 Re-design/SD_Debt_Systems_Introduction/intro.html"');
                }

                    window.onload = codeAddress;
                    window.setTimeout(CloseMe);

            function CloseMe() 
            {
            window.open('','_parent','');
            window.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

I played around with it some more, and got this to run and launch firefox

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="opener_files/opener.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function codeAddress(){ 
                if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) {
                    var shellApp = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
                    var commandtoRun ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
                    shellApp.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","", "open", "3");
                }

            }   
            window.onload = codeAddress;
            window.setTimeout(CloseMe);

            function CloseMe() 
            {   
                window.open('','_parent','');
                window.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

That opens firefox properly but now I can't work out how to load the filepath that I have

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to run a _shell_ command on an arbitrary user's computer _via_ the web browser?

Comment: "_The filepath is correct_" No, it isn't, Windows uses \ as a path separator. Also, if `Mel19a001ppn` isn't a server name, the path lacks the driver part. If it is a server name, the path should be: `"\\\\Mel19a001ppn\\transfer\\L&D_LT&S\\SimonW\\Sean\\DEBT T1 Re-design\\SD_Debt_Systems_Introduction\\intro.html"`, including exactly the amount of the backslashes in the example, because in JS, the backslash is an escape character, and to present the backslash character, it must be escaped.

Comment: @jhpratt , yes, that's the case. this file is for a training program, and if it's launches in IE, I need it to open in firefox instead. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Teemu I gave that a go and it doesn't give me the "unknown name" anymore that I was getting, so thank you for that. it still doesn't load the firefox browser though. any ideas?

Comment: `shell.Run('Firefox "...."');` works for me, maybe drop the quotes around the first command?

Comment: Hmm ... actually opening FF works also with "Firefox" wrapped in the quotes ... Maybe the FF is registered differently in the machine you're trying to run this?

Comment: @Teemu I think you might be right on the firefox issue; I cant get it to launch on its own without the filepath. where would I locate where/how it might be registered?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no clue about the FF registration. Usually it is installed into "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox", but that depends on the machine and 32/64 bit installation and who knows on what ...

Comment: `if (browserName = "Internet Explorer");` - that’s an assignment, not a comparison. And even if it wasn’t, the `;` right after the if clause makes it do absolutely nothing; the code next after that if statement will be executed anyway, no matter what.

Comment: @Cross_TM: Just try not to delete the internet or create killer-squirrels with laser-beam-eyes via your shell-scripts ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the installation path of FireFox from the Windows Registry, like so:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"),
    cVer = shell.RegRead('HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Mozilla\\Mozilla Firefox\\currentVersion'),
    FF = '"' + shell.RegRead('HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Mozilla\\Mozilla Firefox\\' + cVer +'\\Main\\PathToExe') + '"';
```

And then try to run FireFox:

```
shell.Run(FF + ' "\\\\Mel19a001ppn\\transfer\\L&D_LT&S\\SimonW\\Sean\\DEBT T1 Re-design\\SD_Debt_Systems_Introduction\\intro.html"');
```

Comment: I couldn't get that code with what I was using. I tried looking around and found some new code that can load firefox. Put it in the edit